# How to automate : Capture & Page Move on iBooks

Tags: ios, epub, ibooks

Recently I'm getting involved with ePUB.
At this time, iBooks is the best ePUB reader on iPhone/iPad, I think.

Now, I'd like to capture each page of ePUB.
Is it possible to automate it?